# Jquery can not load in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-mobile, cordova, cross-platform

i am developing a simple jquery+phonegap application.
Below is my index.html code

```
<html><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; user-scalable=yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; 
            $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false; 
            </script>                
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
         <script src="jqtouch.min.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function onDeviceReady() {
                alert("Device ready");
             }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                              alert("done");
                              document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); 
                               });

            </script>
        </head>
<body>
   Welcome PhoneGap
</body>
```

Here i m using query external link so i have added external host as ajax.googleapis.com in 
my cordova.plist file.

Still i m not getting alert when i run this code.

Please help me out.

Thanks in adv.
Dhrumil Shah

Answer (score 1):

Load the jQuery Mobile library *before* you try to access the `$.mobile` object.

Basically, HTML is parsed progressively so any libraries need to downloaded and parsed before you can access any object belonging to them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that way also but its not working. I think i don't know how to access external resource from simulator. Can anybody knows how to access that resources.. i tried all the option but not getting success.